# How to read flash attributes after redirection in Spring MVC 3.1?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I would like to know how to read a flash attributes after redirection in Spring MVC 3.1.

I have the following code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView handleGet(...) {
    // I want to see my flash attributes here!
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView handlePost(RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttributes("some", "thing");
    return new ModelAndView().setViewName("redirect:/foo/bar");
  }

}
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `Model`, it should have flash attributes prepopulated:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleGet(Model model) {
  String some = (String) model.asMap().get("some");
  // do the job
}
```

or, alternatively, you can use [`RequestContextUtils#getInputFlashMap`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html#getInputFlashMap%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleGet(HttpServletRequest request) {
  Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
  if (inputFlashMap != null) {
    String some = (String) inputFlashMap.get("some");
    // do the job
  }
}
```

P.S. You can do return `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/foo/bar");` in `handlePost`.

**EDIT**:

JavaDoc says:

> A RedirectAttributes model is empty when the method is called and is
>   never used unless the method returns a redirect view name or a
>   RedirectView.

It doesn't mention `ModelAndView`, so maybe change handlePost to return `"redirect:/foo/bar"` string or `RedirectView`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView handlePost(RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
  redirectAttrs.addFlashAttributes("some", "thing");
  return new RedirectView("/foo/bar", true);
}
```

I use `RedirectAttributes` in my code with `RedirectView` and `model.asMap()` method and it works OK.

Comment: No luck, my Model is coming empty.

Comment: Did you try `RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request)`?

Comment: I will try with returning `RedirectView` then with `String`.

Comment: Thanks, it just worked like a charm by returning a `RedirectView`.

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
@Controller
public class FooController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
    public String handleFoo(RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs)
    {
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("some", "thing");
        return "redirect:/bar";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bar")
    public void handleBar(@ModelAttribute("some") String some)
    {
        System.out.println("some=" + some);
    }
}
```

works in Spring MVC 3.2.2

Comment: just note that you cannot check for "is the attribute filled" on custom objects. the `@ModelAttribute` returns not-null even if there is no object with given name in redirect attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For all those like me who were having problems with seeing the POST url in the browser when a validation would fail.

The POST url is a private url that should not be exposed to users but it was automatically rendered when a validation failed.  i.e. if a field was below a minimum length.  I was using @Valid. I wanted the original GET url of the form to show at all times even when validation bounced back to the form, so I did the following:

```
        if (validation.hasErrors()) {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.story", validation);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("story", story);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/january/2015");
```

where story is the form object representation, redirectAttributes are RedirectAttributes you put in the method signature and validation is the BindingResult.  /january/2015 is the mapping to the GET controller where the form lives.

After this implementation, in the mapping for /january/2015, story comes in intact as follows:

```
Story story= (Story) model.asMap().get("story");
//story from the POST method
```

I had to augment my GET method and check if this was not null.  If not null, then send this to the form else I would send a newly initialized Story type to the form as default behaviour before.

In this manner, I am able to return to the form with the bindingresults intact (errors show on form) but have my GET url in place of the post url.