# How to build cascade controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect

I need to input URL like this `http://localhost:8080/first` and after that my controller must go to `http://localhost:8080/second` and so on until I came to `http://localhost:8080/end`. Its something like recursion. At the end point I need to pring a list.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class CascadeController {    
    @RequestMapping("/first")
    String first(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("list", new ArrayList<String>());
        return "/second";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/second")
    String second(ModelMap model) {
        ((List) model.get("list")).add("A");
        return "/third";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/third")
    String third(ModelMap model) {
        ((List) model.get("list")).add("B");
        return "end";
    }
}
```

end.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<html>
<body>
   <%for(String s : (List<String>) request.getAttribute("list")){%>
      <%=s%>
   <%}%>
</body>
</html>
```

Is anybody can explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What result are you getting and how does it differ from your expectations?

Comment: Did you hear about Spring Web Flow? Maybe useful..

Comment: I can't use Spring WF, only MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the user need to see the data placed on the model for the /first or /second page?
If not, how about try changing:

`return "/second";`  to  `return "redirect:/second";`

and

`return "/third";`  to `return "redirect:/third";`

If the user needs to see the data on /first or /second page for X time, how about doing the redirect from javascript?

**Edited:**
How about flash attributes, see this post: [reading flash attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763779/how-to-read-flash-attributes-after-redirection-in-spring-mvc-3-1)

```
  @RequestMapping("/first")
    String first(ModelMap model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        model.put("list", new ArrayList<String>());
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("list", new ArrayList<String>());
        return "redirect:/second";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/second")
    String second(ModelMap model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        List list = (List) model.get("list");
        list.add("A");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("list", list);
        return "redirect:/third";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/third")
    String third(ModelMap model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        List list = (List) model.get("list");
        list.add("B");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("list", list);
        return "end";
    }
```

Comment: >> Does the user need to see the data placed on the model for the /first or /second page? Yes, I need to save a model.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at [Spring Webflow](http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/). Copied from the project description:

> The sweet spot for Spring Web Flow are stateful web applications with
>   controlled navigation [...] these scenarios have in common is
>   one or more of the following traits:
>
> - There is a clear start and an end point.
> - The user must go through a set of screens in a specific order.
> - The changes are not finalized until the last step.
> - Once complete it shouldn't be possible to repeat a transaction accidentally