# Flash Attributes are not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, appfuse

I have got an Spring MVC project (AppFuse) and Flash attributes are not transmitted to the GET request.

What I do:
In the transmitter method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(Entity entity, BindingResult errors, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, RedirectAttributes ra){
   ...
   ra.addFlashAttribute("id", entity.getId().toString());
   success = "redirect:somePage";
   ...
   return success;
}
```

In the receiver method, I cannot get the passed flash attribute. I tried these approaches:

- by ModelMap
- by Model
- by @ModelAttribute("id")

Comment: Are you using Model in the receiver method? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11763834/65681

Comment: I tried using Model in the receiver method, but it did not work. I also tried with ModelMap, but that did not solved the issue, nor @ModelAttribute.The key was to place single slash in redirect path (making the path absolute). Nothing else helped me. After adding the slash, all 3 approaches started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the redirecting string. Working one is:

```
success = "redirect:/somePage";
```

More correct solution is:

```
success = "redirect:" + request.getContextPath() + "/somePage";
```

Double slash redirect is also non-working:

```
success = "redirect://somePage";
```