# list of objects from controller to jsp and <c:forEach>

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I try to send list of Employee from Spring MVC controller and then use it in jsp with forEach loop but receive blank page.

What is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getuserbylastname", method = RequestMethod.GET)
Employee employee, ModelMap model) {
public ModelAndView searchUserByLastname(@ModelAttribute("employee")Employee employee, ModelMap model) {
    List emplList = new ArrayList();
    EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAOImpl();
    emplList = employeeDAO.getByLastname(employee.getLastName());// here list size is 2
    model.addAttribute("listOfEmployees", emplList);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/searchbysurnameresult", "Model", emplList);
}
```

**jsp:**

```
<html>
 <body>
 <c:forEach var="employee" items="${Model}">
   <c:out value="${employee.firstName}"/>
 </c:forEach>
 </body>
</html>
```

P.S.I have a taglib url in JSP but there is a problem to display it like code at this site

Comment: You have to write items=¨${listOfEmployees}¨ in JSP page in c:forEach tag.

Answer (score 2):

When you redirect your page this issue occurs and the data present in your model attribute becomes null. `Spring MVC` has added new type of attribute said as `FlashAttributes`. Use them to solve this issue.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763779/how-to-read-flash-attributes-after-redirection-in-spring-mvc-3-1) has more information on how to use Flash attributes.

Comment: thanks! I've just tried RedirectView and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "getuserbylastname", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RedirectView searchUserByLastname(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
      List emplList = new ArrayList();
      EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAOImpl();
      emplList = employeeDAO.getByLastname(employee.getLastName());
      redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("listOfEmployees", emplList);
      return new RedirectView("searchbysurnameresult", true);
}
```