# Using flash attributes when redirecting to a JSP page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following situation in my MVC controller

```
    for (String key : form.keySet())
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute(key, form.getFirst(key));

    return "redirect:" + page;
```

`page` is `/secure/admin/pages/userPreferences.jsp` and I have a single `username` attribute added to the flash attributes

From the JSP page, how do I access that `username` flash attributes. But I have no idea of how!

I have tried both `${param.username}` and `${username}` but none worked. I tried to dump all `${param}` and request attributes but found nothing in the JSP

Similar question: [How to read flash attributes after redirection in Spring MVC 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763779/how-to-read-flash-attributes-after-redirection-in-spring-mvc-3-1) - the difference is that *they* want to read flash attributes from MVC controller rather than from JSP view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you redirect, the other controller will be called.

What you can do is to transfer the flashed Arguments as a normal model attributes:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected String get(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) { // redirect request

    Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
    if (inputFlashMap != null) {
        String name = (String) inputFlashMap.get("username");
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
    }

    return "page";
}
```

The other option is to access the flash map in your jsp. Look at this implementation of :

```
public static Map<String, ?> getInputFlashMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (Map<String, ?>) request.getAttribute(DispatcherServlet.INPUT_FLASH_MAP_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

with:

```
public static final String INPUT_FLASH_MAP_ATTRIBUTE = DispatcherServlet.class.getName() + ".INPUT_FLASH_MAP";
```

unfortunately the dot in the attribute name do not allow you to access the map directly. You will have to do it by using `<% code %>`

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: if I use `redirectAttrs.addAttribute` instead of `addFlashAttribute` I get two effects:

1. JSP page will see `${param.username}` and act accordingly
2. I get that username in the query string (e.g. `userPreferences.jsp?username=jdoe`) which is not really exciting, but actually allows refreshing the page

This is a workaround because I preferred to have parameters invisible - which is the main reason one uses flash attributes.

Comment: This worked for me to get the value in the JSP!! Thanks! But what's the difference between `addAttribute` and `addFlashAttribute` ?